# Setting a Google Analytics event inside an Ajax form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-analytics

I am trying to set a Google Analytics event on a lightbox contact form of a WP plugin.

I have added the onSubmit call inside the  and although it renders well without problem, the events are not logged into Analytics

```
<form action="#" method="post" class="modal-contact_form" onSubmit="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Contact V1', \'<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ?>', '1']);">
```

The event seems not to log in, because there's a new Thank You lightbox window which appears after you hit Send on Contact form

This is teh original code of the Thank you lightbox window

```
            $.post( modal_contact_params.ajax_url, data, function( response ) {
                if ( response == "SUCCESS" ) {

                    $('#facebox .content form.modal-contact_form').slideUp();
                    $('#facebox .notice').remove();
                    var agent_name = jQuery("#ninety_mcf_user_name").html();
                    if(agent_name=='This Agent'){
                        $('#facebox .modal-contact_messages').html('<div class="notice success"><div><p><strong>' + modal_contact_params.i18n_sent + '</strong> ' + modal_contact_params.i18n_thanks + '</p></div></div>'
    );
}
    else
{
                        $('#facebox .modal-contact_messages').html('<div class="notice success"><div><p><strong>' + modal_contact_params.i18n_sent + '</strong>Thanks, your email has been sent to '+agent_name+'</p></div></div>'
);
                    }

                }
```

I am trying to insert the _gaq.push Event call at the end of Success lightbox but I can't make it

I have tried all sorts of combinations and none of them render, as they all produce errors on GA Debug console in Chrome

One of my many different tries

```
</div>' + { _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Contact V1', 'Send', '1']); } +''
);
```

Thanks and I hope it's easy enough for SO gurus to help me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to append the function call to the string, but execute it...

```
...</div>');
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Contact V1', 'Send', '1']);
...
```

Comment: I tried that one too, but it didn't work. It produced an Unexpected identifier error on GA Debug console of Google Chrome.

Comment: Unexpected identifier is generally a JS syntax error, in the snippet you provided you are missing a } to close the function. Try running your code through JSLint.